# How to get each variation's stock quantity woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm showing product variations as a list instead of a drop down using the code below (may help some people). What I'm trying to add to this is the stock count for each variation.

I.e something like this would be ideal to drop in.

`<?php echo $product->get_stock_quantity(); ?>`

Current code using to display variations in a table/list.

```
function woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart() {
    global $product, $post;
    $variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {
    ?>
    <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>"method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $value['variation_id']?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
        <?php
        if(!empty($value['attributes'])){
            foreach ($value['attributes'] as $attr_key => $attr_value) {
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $attr_key?>" value="<?php echo $attr_value?>">
            <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b><?php echo implode('/', $value['attributes']);?></b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $value['price_html'];?>
                    </td>
                    <td>

                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo apply_filters('single_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ), $product->product_type); ?></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the stock of product variations with the following:

```
<?php

global $product;


     if ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {

     foreach ( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ) {

     //gets the product variation based on its id
     $get_product_variation = wc_get_product( $variation_id );

     //get each variations stock quantity
     $product_variation_stock = $get_product_variation->get_stock_quantity();

     //do whatever with variation stock
     echo '<p> Variation: ' . $variation_id . ' - Stock: ' . $product_variation_stock . '</p>';

     }
  }

 ?>
```

Hope that helps! Tested and works. Good luck.